# register Publish Filter for IMessageScheduler

Tags: filter, rabbitmq, masstransit

I wrote a publish filter that has worked correct when I publish a message by IPublishEndpoint.now I need to have this filter when I publish a message by IMessageScheduler.

the following code is called when I publish a non schedule message by IPublishEndpoint.

```
 public class IntegrationEventPublishFilter<T> : IFilter<PublishContext<T>> where T : class
{       
    public IntegrationEventPublishFilter()
    {}

    public Task Send(PublishContext<T> context, IPipe<PublishContext<T>> next)
    {
        // do something
        return next.Send(context);
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
    // do something
    }
}
```

how can I have this filter when I publish a scheduled message by IMessageScheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Chris Patterson said in above answer/comments, we need to register a filter for `SendContext<T>` while publishing a message by IMessageScheduler. in this case we have the following code :

```
 public class MySendFilter<T> : IFilter<SendContext<T>> where T : class
   {       

public Task Send(SendContext<T> context, IPipe<SendContext<T>> next)
{
    // do something
    return next.Send(context);
}

public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
{
// do something
}
}
```

and also you must register this filter as a `SendFilter` in MassTransit Registration.

```
 x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            
                e.UseSendFilter(typeof(MySendFilter<>), context);
                ///...
            
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `SchedulePublish` or `ScheduleSend`? Either way, you may need to add a filter for `SendContext<T>` and add it in additional to the publish filter, since the message scheduler may be using send to schedule the message – depending upon how you configured the message scheduler.

Comment: we use _messageScheduler.SchedulePublish(). and unfortunately PublishContext<T> isn't called in Masstransit pipeline.

Comment: Because SchedulePublish ultimately sends the message to the scheduler.

Comment: It's correct, but I mean when the time of scheduled message gets arrive, and the message is published, PublishContext<T> isn't called.

Comment: Nope, it sure isn't. It's already at the broker and/or scheduler, no longer in MT's pervue.

Comment: it makes sense. but how can I have a filter like PublishContext<T> when I publish a message by the messageScheduler. actually I set some logics into rabbitMQ[MT] headers like http requestId and userId in this filer. with this limit I'll miss my headers.

Comment: Create a `SendContext<T>` filter instead, nothing you want is specific to publish. Or better yet, create both of them to ensure complete coverage.